# Suggestions on how to extend WordPress shortcode Edit button without losing its functionality

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

[image: WordPress Gallery Shortcode]

I'd like to extend the WordPress shortcode Edit button and have my own functionality onClick and at the same time don't lose/overwrite the one the WordPress has.

Here is the code I have right now (which works) but this overwrites the WordPress onClick which doesn't work any more and obviously I don't want to have that.

```
editor.addButton( 'wp_view_edit', {
  tooltip : 'Edit',
  icon    : 'dashicon dashicons-edit',
  onclick : function() {
    // here goes my code for custom functionality
  }
} );
```

And here is the original code from WP found in /wp-incldes/js/tinymcs/plugins/wp-view/plugins.js

```
editor.addButton( 'wp_view_edit', {
    tooltip: 'Edit|button', // '|button' is not displayed, only used for context
    icon: 'dashicon dashicons-edit',
    onclick: function() {
        var node = editor.selection.getNode();

        if ( isView( node ) ) {
            wp.mce.views.edit( editor, node );
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just copy the `onclick` function contents into your own onclick function, and add your functionality before / after?

Comment: Yes, that work out with a little bit of code added to check that the Edit button is attached to a shortcode out of my stack otherwise execute the WP core one.